# Caffe installation in anaconda in MacBook Air and catalina

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I use MacBook Air, with catalina OS. The conda version I use is 4.9.2. I am trying to install caffe with conda using the following sequence of commands in my homebrew shell:

```
conda create -n mycaffe python
conda activate mycaffe
conda install opencv
conda install caffe
```

All the above works successfully except the "conda install caffe" that gives the following error:

```
conda install caffe                                  
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

**PackagesNotFoundError**: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- caffe

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
Suggestions would greatly help!

Comment: There is not a Conda build of `caffe` for the **osx-64** platform. I suspect the lack of NVIDIA support undermines the motivation needed to maintain such a build.

Comment: Thanks. This is sad. OK. Let me try to pull a request from GitHub and download the source code of Caffe and compile it. Any suggestions for a code compilation of Caffe in Mac OS X?